# ¿Cómo extraer los caracteres y guardarlos en una lista?

Tags: c#, lista

Tengo este código en c# pero quería saber cómo extraer las letras y al imprimir no me aparece nada.

**Ejemplo** se ingresa: a+b*2/c+4+a

Y queria saber como guardar las que son letras en otra lista.

```
List<string> Expresion = new List<string>();//lista donde se va a guardar la expresion ingresada

List<List<string>> Letras = new List<List<string>>();// lista donde solo se va a guardar las que son letras de la expresion ingresada

bool letra_ = true;
char vocal;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Expresion.Add(txtExpresion.Text);// se guarda la expresion
        MessageBox.Show("La expresion se guardo");

foreach (var item in Letras) // un forech para saber si es una letra o no
        {
            if (letra_)
            {
                letra_ = false;// si no encuentra alguna letra en la expresion va a continuar
                continue;
            }

            if (letra(Convert.ToChar(item)))
            {
                vocal = Convert.ToChar(item);
                break;//cuando encuentre un letra se va detener 
            }

            caja += string.Format("Letra{0}",item[0]);//se Guarda en la posicion 0

        }
        MessageBox.Show(caja);// se imprime caja

private bool letra(char letrA)//metodo donde estan las vocales
    {
        char[] voca_l = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
        return voca_l.Contains(letrA);
    }
```

Comment: hay ahi un continue y un break que no deberian existir.. podrias explicar tu codigo linea por linea para ver cual es la idea? vas a ver, que la idea es bastante confusa

Comment: ¿Por qué se utiliza una lista de string para almacenar la expresión? ¿O se pueden analizar varias listas? ¿En que momento se le asigna un valor a la lista Letras? La variable item una lista de string, probablemente te está dando una excepción al ejecutar el programa porque no es un argumento válido para el método Convert.ToChar. Además, break rompe el flujo de control, al utilizarlo estas evitando que se termine de recorrer la expresión con el foreach.

Answer (score 1):

Usa `Where` de LinQ sobre la cadena:

```
var letras = entrada.Where(c => Regex.Match(new String(c, 1), @"[a-zA-Z]").Success).ToList();
```

La instrucción anterior te guarda en `letras` (lista) todas las letras que tuviera `entrada`, puedes ver el código funcionando [aquí](https://rextester.com/KXNOH77192).