# Separar letras y números c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, lista

Tengo este código en c# el cual ingreso

> a+b*2/c+4+a

y quiero que se se separen las letras de los números y estén en un listbox .

Este es mi código y quería ver si voy bien utilizo listas para almacenar los datos es decir almaceno las letras y otro para almacenar la ecuación ingresada.

```
    List<List<string>> Expresion = new List<List<string>>();
    List<string> Num = new List<string>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Num.Add(txtExpresion.Text);
        Expresion.Add(Num);
    }

    private bool consonante_(char Vowel)
    {
        char[] consonate_ = { 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'Ñ', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
        return consonate_.Contains(Vowel);
    }

    char vocaL;
    private void consM()
    {
        string nombre_ = txtExpresion.Text;

        bool Conso_ = true;
        foreach (char letra in nombre_)
        {
            if (Conso_)
            {
                Conso_ = false;
                continue;
            }
            if (consonante_(letra))
            {
                vocaL = letra;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Hay alguna razón por la que utilizas listas? Basta con almacenar la expresión en una variable de tipo string

Comment: @JYass es obligatorio que se almacene en una lista

Comment: Entonces Num y Expresion debería ser una lista de caracteres: List<char>. Cuando usas List<List<string>> lo que estás declarando es una lista de listas de cadenas. Con respecto al método ConsM(): ¿por qué evaluas una variable booleana, si el propósito del foreach es recorrer todos los elementos de una lista? Al utilizar esa variable booleana, evitas la primera comparación, y luego, cuando encuentras una letra, rompes la iteración con el break. Ni la variable booleana ni el continue ni el break deberían ir en tu código.

Comment: Podrias decirme en que se diferencia esta pregunta de esta otra que publicaste anteriormente? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/252837/324. Recuerda que no esta bien visto volver a publicar una pregunta que ya hiciste. Si necesitas hacer cambios, hacelo sobre la original si no fue lo suficientemente clara